# Отображение XML с помощью AJAX и Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

Есть XML-файл, как правильно сделать его отображение с помощью AJAX и Javascript?
Если я правильно понял суть, то на выходе должен будет получиться html. Но вот не совсем понимаю как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

XML - это просто набор данных, никак не предназначенный для отображения. Для отображения XML применяется XSLT, которое конвертирует исходный XML в другой формат (обычно html). Некоторые браузеры, могут использовать некую умолчательную xsl. Но лучше всего написать свое преобразование и вызывать его после получения исходного набора данных